# aiohttp shows error 403 forbidden

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

I'm trying to download an MP4 file from this website but it doesn't work because it shows error 403 forbidden when I visit the link:

This is what I am using to try and download the files:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
    async with cs.get('https://cdn-e1.streamable.com/video/mp4/kphjz.mp4') as r:
        if r.status == 200:
            img = await r.read()
            with open('C:/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Streamables/' + url.split('/')[-1], 'wb') as f:
                f.write(img)
                f.close()
                print('Downloaded {0}'.format(url.split('/')[-1]))
```

It does nothing because `r.status` does not equal 200 but 403. How can I bypass this?

Comment: [403](https://httpstatuses.com/403) means you are not authorized to access the url. If you open this url on web browser you get same erro. You probably need HTTP authentication headers to be able to access that url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Looks like I should have used this:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers={"Referer": "https://streamable.com"}) as cs:
```

Needed the `headers={"Referer": "https://streamable.com"}` part.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that I was making too many requests too quickly. As soon as I slowed it down it was fine.